# OnePlus 2 - cannot get adb to work with my device (cannot find device)

Tags: android, adb, windows-10, oneplustwo

I am trying to setup the Windows drivers for my OnePlus 2 device to allow me to connect to my device currently running the following command doesn't show the connected device :

```
$ adb devices
```

All I see is the following :-

```
$ adb devices
$ List of devices attached
```

Nothing else is shown - I can see within the Control Panel under Other devices there is the ADB Interface with the warning to confirm that the drivers haven't been installed, even though I have installed the USB drivers that come wit hthe device and you attach the phone to the computer and restarted Windows (10).

Can anyone suggest what the problem may be?

Comment: Did you enable the developer options on your Oneplus 2?

Comment: Yeh I have enabled this - I should have mentioned that in my original post

Comment: Have you tried using the samsung universal driver?

Comment: Tried the Samsung Universal Driver and still no joy... i will keep trying

Comment: FIXED! will post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working by doing the following :

- Install Samsung Universal Driver first
- Select PTP USB configuration in the phone settings
- Go to Device Manager
- While phone is plugged in (important) select ADB Inteface and select to update the driver, from here you will find the Universal ADB device and it works then... annoying as it is a Samsung driver for a OnePlus 2 device.

Answer (score 0):

Go to play store

Download PdaNet+ app and install in device(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet&hl=en).

Download desktop version of PdaNet and install in PC or Laptop.

Open PdsNet app in device and enable USB and connect with your IDE(Android studio/eclipse).